# How to take an integral using half angle trigonometric substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

So i have this question which is asking to take the integral using a predefined trigonometric substitution which is $$u=\tan\frac{x}{2}$$
and the integral equation is $$\int\frac{\sin x\ dx}{(6\cos x-2)(3-2\sin x)}$$ How would i go on about this problem? Because to begin with i do not know how i would even use the given substitution method. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This substitution is used for integrals involving **only** trigonometric expressions. This method is very useful as it transforms the trigonometric integral into just rational integral. You should know how to write $\sin x, \cos x, \tan x$ in terms of $\tan \frac{x}{2}$

(try proving)

$\sin x=\dfrac{2\tan \frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}$

$\cos x=\dfrac{1-\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}$

$\tan x=\dfrac{2\tan \frac{x}{2}}{1-\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}$

To find $dx$ in terms of $du$, differentiate both sides.

$u = \tan \dfrac{x}{2}$

$du = \sec^2 \dfrac{x}{2} \dfrac{1}{2} dx = (1+\tan^2 \dfrac{x}{2})\dfrac{1}{2} dx=(1+u^2)\dfrac{1}{2}dx \Rightarrow dx=\dfrac{2}{1+u^2}du$

For this example, The integral is converted to,

$$\int\dfrac{\sin x}{(6cosx-2)(3-2sinx)}dx=\int\dfrac{\dfrac{2u}{1+u^2}}{(6\dfrac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}-2 )(3-2\dfrac{2u}{1+u^2})}\dfrac{2}{1+u^2}du$$
$$=\int\dfrac{4u}{(1+u^2)(6-6u^2-2-2u^2)(3+3u^2-4u)}du$$
$$=\int\dfrac{-4u}{(1+u^2)(8u^2-4)(3u^2-4u+3)}du$$
$$=\int\dfrac{3u^2-4u+3-(3u^2+3)}{(1+u^2)(8u^2-4)(3u^2-4u+3)}du$$
$$=\int\dfrac{du}{(1+u^2)(8u^2-4)}-\int\dfrac{3\ du}{(8u^2-4)(3u^2-4u+3)}$$

and integrate using partial fractions and substitute again $u=\tan \dfrac{x}{2}$.

Look how nicely the trigonometric integral(which made no sense) is transformed to a rational integral(which can be solved at least by brute force).
Try more examples.

(
You will get to realize that some problems looks like can be solved using half angle substitutions but really can be solved without substitution. Example
$$\int\dfrac{\sin x}{(\cos x -2)(2\cos x +3)}dx$$ 
)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a right triangle that has a side opposite angle $\frac{x}{2}$ of length $u=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ and an adjacent side of length 1. Obviously, $\tan \frac{x}{2} =\frac{opposite}{adjacent}= \frac{\tan\frac{x}{2}}{1}=\tan\frac{x}{2}=u$. What would the Hypotenuse be?
[image]

Having done that, its a simple matter to find expressions for $\cos\frac{x}{2}$ and $\sin\frac{x}{2}$ (using the same triangle).

Noting that $$\cos 2t=\cos^2 t - \sin^2t$$
and that
$$\sin2t = 2\sin t\cos t$$
we can make the substitution $t=\frac{x}{2}$ to find expressions (in terms of $u$) for $\cos x$ and $\sin x$.

Lastly we note that $$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\tan\frac{x}{2} = \frac{\sec^2\frac{x}{2}}{2}=\frac{\tan^2\frac{x}{2}+1}{2}=\frac{u^2+1}{2}$$

Putting all this information together yourself (as opposed to just parroting formulas) will give you a superior understanding of this substitution method.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$x=2arctan(u)$$, that gives $$dx=\frac{2}{u^2+1}du$$

Furthermore, we have $$cos(x)=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$$

and $$sin(x)=\frac{2u}{u^2+1}$$

Inserting those terms, you get a rational function of $u$. Try it from here.

Answer (score 0):

By letting $u=\tan\frac{x}2$, we get

$$\int\frac{\sin x}{(6\cos x-2)(3-2\sin x)}d x=\int\frac{u d u}{(1-2u^2)(3u^2-4u+3)}\\
=\frac{8}{49}\int\frac{(9u+4)du}{1-2u^2}+\frac{12}{49}\int\frac{(9u-8)du}{3u^2-4u+3},$$
the later two are both integration of rational functions.
$$\int\frac{(9u+4)du}{1-2u^2}=9\int\frac{udu}{1-2u^2}+4\int\frac{du}{1-2u^2}\\
=-\frac94\int\frac{d(1-2u^2)}{1-2u^2}+\sqrt2\int\left(\frac{1}{1-\sqrt2u}+\frac{1}{1-\sqrt2u}\right)du\\
=-\frac94\ln|1-2u^2|+\sqrt2\ln\frac{1+\sqrt2u}{1-\sqrt2u}+C_1$$
$$\int\frac{(9u-8)du}{3u^2-4u+3}=\frac13\int\frac{9\left(u-\frac23\right)-2}
{\left(u-\frac23\right)^2+\frac59}du=3\int\frac{\left(u-\frac23\right)}
{\left(u-\frac23\right)^2+\frac59}du+\frac23\int\frac{du}
{\left(u-\frac23\right)^2+\frac59}\\
=\frac32\int\frac{d\left(u-\frac23\right)^2}{\left(u-\frac23\right)^2+\frac59}
+\frac2{\sqrt5}\int\frac{d\frac3{\sqrt5}\left(u-\frac23\right)}{\left[\frac3{\sqrt5}\left(u-\frac23\right)\right]^2+1}\\
=\frac32\ln\left(u^2-\frac43u+1\right)-\frac2{\sqrt5}\arctan\left[\frac3{\sqrt5}\left(u-\frac23\right)\right]+C_2$$